# How to use the proxies returned from javascript in dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm currently calling a function in JavaScript from dart that takes in a JSON string and a success callback.

The callback from JavaScript should be returning a response as a JSON string. However I am unable to get this information from the returned Proxy in dart. When debugging all I can see on the Proxy is _id, _port and hashCode.

How do I go about getting the required information from the Proxy?

Code snippets:

```
void init()
{
  _mJSProxy= js.retain(new js.Proxy(js.context.Test));}
}

void testRequest(String p_request)
{
  _mJSProxy.test(js.map(p_request), new js.Callback.once(onCallbackSuccess));
}

void onCallbackSuccess(var response, var httpRequest)
{
  // response & httpRequest is a Proxy
  // How to get the required information from them?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `js.Proxy` object is used when the returned type is not a `bool`, `num`, `String` or `html.Element`. When a `js.Proxy` is returned you have to know what is the structure on the underlying Js object to use it. For instance if the Js object is an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XMLHttpRequest) you will be able to use it like this :

```dart
js.Proxy p = // proxy on XMLHttpRequest
String result = p.responseText; 
// '.responseText' is handled by noSuchMethod and the call is done on Js side
```

In your case, if `response` is a `Proxy` and you want to copy the Json structure in Dart you can use :

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

String jsonValue = js.context.JSON.stringify(reponse);
Map dartJson = JSON.decode(jsonValue);
```

*Side note* : you have to use a `Map` as parameter for `js.map(...)`. In your code you use a `String`.